# Cast double from Any object, that suppose to be Int or Double

Tags: swift

I have object in my dictionary `[String: Any]`, that could be an Int or Double. In my model i have variable that is Double, and i need to perform a cast. Now i doing following:

```
if let price = dict["price"] as? Double { self.price = price }
if let price = dict["price"] as? Int { self.price = Double(price) }
```

Is there any way to write my code shortly and more clean?

Comment: **if let price = dict["price"] as? NSNumber** ???

Comment: Where is the `[String: Any]` coming from? If it's JSON parsing, I would strongly recommend using `JSONDecoder` instead, which will take care of the `Int` to `Double` mapping for you automatically, while avoiding the `NSNumber` casting behaviour of accepting boolean values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `case let` to make it clear that there is only one thing being cast:

```
switch dict["price"] {
    case let price as Double: { self.price = price }
    case let price as Int:    { self.price = Double(price) }
    default: break
}
```

Although the code is slightly longer, it is less repetitive, because `dict["price"]` is used only once.

If you are certain that `"price"` key is going to be there, and it is going to be a number, you could use this code:

```
self.price = (dict["price"] as! NSNumber).doubleValue
```

Despite being shorter, the second approach requires a lot more certainty from the programmer in order not to break. The first code would leave `price` unset if anything goes wrong, while the second code is going to crash.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban Please see the edit. The second approach is shorter, but if you have any doubt about the data inside the `dict`, you should stay away from this approach, because it is prone to crashing your app.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban Please also note Sh_Khan's answer, it offers a great "middle ground" between shortness (three lines instead of one) and safety (always safe, even when there's no key or the key is of a wrong type).

Comment: Note also that casting to `NSNumber` and getting the `doubleValue` will succeed for boolean values – turning `true` into `1` and `false` into `0`, which may be unexpected for your use case.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try

```
if let price = dict["price"] as? NSNumber {
  self.price = price.doubleValue
}
```